# Retrieve Firebase Data As A Custom Object?

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to make handling database data easier in an app that I am creating.

This is the object being used to upload the data to Firebase. This is also the object I want to convert the data back into to be used by the app's interface:

```
class WYRQuestionDBModel(var side1Question: String,
    var side2Question : String,
    var side1Count : Int,
    var side2Count : Int)
```

So far I am getting this result:

```
{side2Question=empty, side2Count=1, side1Count=1, side1Question=empty}
```

How can I convert this back to the object above in Kotlin?

Here is the function that I ma trying to achieve this in:

```
Firebase.database.reference.child(Constants.wyrDBQuestionLocation)
        .child(randQuestionId.toString())
        .get()
        .addOnFailureListener { task ->
            Log.i("Get WYR Question Status", "Failed: " + task.message.toString())
            //All values remain the same
        }.addOnSuccessListener {
            Log.i("Get WYR Question Status", "Success")
            Log.i("Request Data Result", it.value.toString())
            dataRequestResult = it.value.toString()

            //Convert the data to an object here

            Log.i("Database Result", dataRequestResult.toString())
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you see the Firebase documentation on [reading and writing data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write)? The `Post` class in there should be a pretty direct template for your `WYRQuestionDBModel` class.

If you follow the pattern outline in those docs, reading a `` can be done with:

```
val question = it.value.getValue<WYRQuestionDBModel >()
```

Note: be sure to include the `-ktx` extensions version of the SDK.